# Реализация BottomSheetFragment

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Хочу реализовать выдвигающееся `BottomMenu` как в стандартном мессенджере на Android 6, но не могу понять, в какую сторону копать. На SO находил подобные запросы, но на них либо еще нет ответа, либо предлагают использовать сторонние библиотеки. Но, я так понимаю, что реализовывалось это стандартными методами. В принципе, что-то похожее можно найти при создании нового проекта в `Android Studio` под названием `"Scrolling Activity"`, но там она является полноэкранной версией. Короче говоря, подскажите, если кто-то работал с этим. Вот скриншоты того, как это выглядит.

[image: 1st image] [image: 2nd image]

Т.е. при нажатии на изображение контакта получается изображение на 1 скриншоте. При дальнейшем "слайде" вверх `CollapsingToolbar` сворачивается и открывается весь контент (как на 2 скриншоте). При обратном "слайде" оно опять сворачивается обратное состояние.

**UPD** как подсказали, это - BottomSheetFragment. Возможно кто-то делал такую его реализацию?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Наверное вы говорите о BottomSheetFragment

Comment: @ЮрийСПб посмотрел - вроде, оно, но я не до конца уверен.Ведь там  при полном раскрытии оно превращается в, своего рода, Activity со своим toolbar'ом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Он может появляться не полностью, не во всю высоту на экране.

Он может иметь ограниченную высоту и не перекрывать весь контент

Он может разворачиваться/сворачиваться жестом.